# Dealing with opacity in adobe illustrator using the Numberpad keys

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, transparency

Can someone please tell me if I need to adjust how can I deal with **opacity** without going in the *properties section* in adobe illustrator?

I am familiar with *Adobe Photoshop* and *Figma*, and we can simply do this by clicking the number pad numbers. But I don't know why adobe illustrator does not have this feature.

For your reference please see the screenshot below.
[image]

Is there any other way to handle this?
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need to assign your own keyboard shortcut. Go to Edit> Keyboard Shortcuts and then under Tools scroll down. You can set the Opacity in 10% increments.

[image]

Otherwise, if you click into the percentage field for Opacity in the Properties Panel (or most any of the other of the numeric panels) you can use the up/ down arrows to increase or decrease Opacity by 1% or use shift + up/down arrow to change the opacity in 10% jumps. I use this method rather than the sliders or drop down settings because, with the preview box checked, you can visually see the results of each setting.